# Android&Quickblox: Ho to get QBCustomObject id?

Tags: android, quickblox

I can't get the id field from a QBCustomObject after retrieving them from the database.
I tried:

```
customObject.getId()
customObject.get("id")
customObject.get("_id")
```

But both of them return null.
The response of the get request is:

```
 '{"class_name":"Commento","skip":0,"limit":0,"items":[{"_id":"58764867a28f9a83b00000d6","_parent_id":null,"created_at":1484146791,"post_id":"news1542333154","testo":"un commento","updated_at":1484146791,"user_id":22399324},{"_id":"58764865a0eb47eecc00003a","_parent_id":null,"created_at":1484146789,"post_id":"news1542333154","testo":"un commento","updated_at":1484146789,"user_id":22399324}]}'
```

The value I'm trying to get is "58764867a28f9a83b00000d6".

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the correct way is to call
     customObject.getCustomId()